# Importing Data from Excel File in PyCharm

Tags: python, excel, pycharm

I've been having some issues reading in data from an excel file using python. I'm using PyCharm, so I don't know if that may be the problem, but I've tried 3 or 4 tutorials and I haven't had any luck.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\lfasanello\PycharmProjects\excel2\sales.xlsx')
print(data.sheet_names)


import xlrd

loc = r"C:/Users/lfasanello/PycharmProjects/excel2/sales.xlsx"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))
```

In this code I'm trying two different methods of reading in the excel data, and neither are working. In the first section where I import pandas, I moved the sales.xlsx file into the working directory, so I don't think thats the problem. In the second attempt where I import xlrd, where I set loc = file path, I'm getting the error:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I've tried some work-arounds like putting r in front of the file path like this:
r"C:\Users\lfasanello\Desktop\sales.xlsx"

I've also tried double back slashes, like this:
"C:\\Users\\lfasanello\\Desktop\\sales.xlsx"

But even when I don't get an error, the program isn't printing anything. If someone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Use `loc = "<your-location>"` and not like this `loc=("<your-location>")`.

Comment: And I don't understand why you need to keep it inside two braces like these `()`. This will make it consider the input as tuple.

Comment: `r` is only required if you have `'\'` in the path, not if the path has `'/'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the data with this code:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\lfasanello\Desktop\sales.xlsx')
print(data)
```

I think something may have been messed up with my installation of Pycharm or it was a problem with the file path. Also, the excel data I was attempting to import had over 1 million rows, so after I reduced that number substantially it worked.